# Do eyebrows grow back when shaved?

Tags: biology, hair

I have heard the claim that if you shave your eyebrows, they will never grow back. I have even heard that surgeons try as much as they can not to shave a person's eyebrows unless absolutely necessary.

Is there any evidence behind this claim? Will eyebrows really never grow back when shaved?

Comment: Adam Savage once lost his eyebrows to a flame and it grew back

Comment: It's easy enough to find out. If you don't want to risk living the rest of your life without brows, just shave the forehead of a friend/spouse/roommate while they sleep!

Comment: @Flimzy, or if you want to look constantly surprized.

Comment: I shaved half off a friend's eyebrows once - they both grew back just fine.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm not sure he/she consider you their friend anymore. :P

Comment: By what mechanism would this work? How would the hair follicle even "know" that the hair have been cut off and thus stop growing? Does anyone really believe this?

Comment: I’m questioning the notability of this claim … I’ve never heard it, and it sounds particularly ludicrous, given that we are commonly confronted with eyebrow growth (why else would some women (and men, of course) get their eyebrows plucked on a regular basis?) …

Comment: I WISH! Then I wouldn't have to keep waxing my eyebrows.

Comment: @Zano: Due to their relative proximity to the brain, eye brow follicles are especially smart.

Comment: @Flimzy: I question that. Head hair is even closer (and thus smarter), but they don't know. Rather I think it must be the close proximity to **the eyes** that does it. The follicles thus _see_ that the hair is shaven off.

Comment: @Zano: Ah, but eye lashes do grow back!  (right?)

Comment: If they didn't grow back, it would mean they didn't grow. And then we would all slowly loose our eyebrows. And we don't. + "I have heard that"? I thought we had a requirement that we needed some sort of source claiming it.

Comment: "I have heard" is not really good claims for a question.

Comment: @LennartRegebro not true. Some things stop growing after reaching a certain stage, often physical maturity.

Comment: @jwenting: Right. In which case, we as adults, would slowly loose our eyebrows. And there is no qualification, it doesn't say "if you are over 80", it must therefore apply to at least all adults.

Comment: Mine did. This is original research, which is why I left it as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes they do grow back

[As this video shows. :-)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LM9p_vWvT9Q)

However, if you prefer something a little more informative you can look at the [growth rates of various follicles](http://www.keratin.com/aa/aa011.shtml), and the references around that article (it's well known eyebrow follicles are the slowest to grow).

It seems likely that surgeons avoid shaving them as they are so slow to grow, rather than because they don't grow at all.

Comment: And in my opinion, they avoid shaving them completely because they change so much the face of a person and are so important for expression...